# Node Creation Takes too long and failed

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger-fabric

I installed Blockchain platform v2 beta then I tried to configure it and add nodes.
My Question is:
is there anyone faced long delay in node creation like CA node for example.
I faced this problem and cannot find from where I can check logs.

Notification Error Image:

[image]

Note:
the node did not be created till now since 2 days.

Comment: Typically the reason why it can take time to spin up any node is due to storage creation.

Comment: it is 2 days now...but ok..now i can check logs and thanks to @Leonardo Carraro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the link to the official IBP documentation where is explained how to retrieve and visualize logs.

[IBM Blockchain Platform - Viewing your node logs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/blockchain?topic=blockchain-ibp-console-manage-console#ibp-console-manage-console-node-logs)

I also suggest you to check if there is any issue in your kubernetes cluster where the IBP is running.

Comment: cluster is new..I created it to deploy the IBM Blockchain platform v2

Answer (score 1):

As per the IBM Cloud documentation,

> If you use Enterprise Plan networks, you can view component logs in a
>   text file format. If you use Starter Plan networks, component logs are
>   gathered by the IBM Cloud Log Analysis service and
>   you can view the logs in Kibana.
>
> Each component generates logs from different activities. This is
>   because each component plays different roles within the Hyperledger
>   Fabric network architecture and transaction flows.
>
> Certificate Authority logs The Certificate Authority manages the
>   identity of participants within the network. In Certificate Authority
>   logs, you can find logs from when participants generate public and
>   private keys to communicate with the network (enroll), or when new
>   members, peers, or applications register with the Certificate
>   Authority. You can also use the CA logs to debug if there are any
>   problems with certificate verification.

So, you should be able to see the logs in the IBM Cloud Log Analysis service. By default, your logs are collected by the Lite Plan of the Log Analysis service. This plan is free and stores your logs for three days before discarding them. It also allows you to search only the first 500 MB of your logs per day. If your network logs exceed 500 MB, you cannot view new logs in Kibana. If your network generates more than 500 MB of logs, or you would like to retain your logs for more than three days, you can upgrade to a paid version of the Log Analysis Service.

For more info, refer the [IBM cloud docs here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/blockchain/howto?topic=blockchain-monitor-blockchain-network)